# Why doesn't Buddy help me survive the Ambush in in City 2?

Tags: another-world

At the end of City 2 (Chapter 5) of *Another World*, after passing a pool of water and knocking a guard out with a glass ball, there is a section where you fall down a pit into an ambush.

After [blasting open the right wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7crWZ.jpg), I run to the right as guards blast behind me. Eventually I hit a dead end with bars blocking my path.

[image: Taking fire at the dead end]

According to [this walkthrough](http://www.visualwalkthroughs.com/anotherworld/city2/city2.htm), I’m supposed to hold out until my friend Buddy pulls me up from the ceiling. However, even after surviving upwards of two minutes, I keep dying in this dead end without any rescue.

I should be seeing Buddy crawling in the ceiling while I run towards the dead end, but for some reason the ceiling vents are empty.

**Why isn’t Buddy coming to save me from the underground ambush?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You need to shoot the chandelier blocking Buddy's path before jumping down.

When you first enter City 2, you can spot [Buddy in the crawlspace below the floor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7644.png). He tries to move forward, but his path is blocked by a hanging rope.

Head to the [bottom of the staircase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dSIz.png) with the teleporter, where you were previously surprise-attacked by a guard. From this staircase, keep heading left for 2 rooms until you see three hanging chandeliers.

Walk up the stairs and shoot the lowest-hanging chandelier to clear Buddy's path.

[image: Shoot this chandelier to free Buddy]
<sub>- [Image courtesy of Visual Walkthroughs](http://www.visualwalkthroughs.com/anotherworld/city2/city2.htm)</sub>